# as3 recursive array function

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, recursion

I have a class called Panels which creates many different types of sprite classes and adds them to the stage or nested sprites on the stage. To create the sprites a SpriteInfo class is sent containing all the required information. Now a SpriteInfo class can have the boolean property of having children objects, where it is true, an array of child SpriteInfo objects are added in an array in the parent SpriteInfo object.

So an array of SpriteInfo objects, some with  children SpriteInfo objects is fed through the class Panels, which creates the sprites and adds them to the parent constructed sprite based on the SpriteInfo structure.

I have been having problems with handling this. I checked other sites and saw that ideally a recursive function should be used with a depth limit for the nested spriteInfo objects in the arrays.

So I wrote a depth checker and initialise function which sends spriteinfo to be processed into a sprite via another constructSprite function which works fine but the problem is the initialise function causes flash memory usage to baloon out without functioning.  I must have done something wrong somewhere but I'm unsure where. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the main functions involved:

```
private function initialise(spritesList:Array, wrapping:int, baseWrapping:int, wrapper:Sprite = null, addWrapper:Boolean = true, noZeroConstruct:Boolean = false):Sprite {
        var spriteListDepth:int = getArrayDepth(spritesList);
        var sprite:Sprite = null;
        if (spritesList !== null){
            for (var i:int = 0; i < spritesList.length; i++) {
                if (spritesList[i].getChildrenPresent()) {
                    var parent:Sprite = constructSprite(spritesList[i]);
                    parent = initialiseChildren(parent, spritesList[i], spriteListDepth);
                    wrapper.addChild(parent);
                } else {
                    sprite = constructSprite(spritesList[i]);
                    wrapper.addChild(sprite);
                }

            }

            if (wrapper != null) {
                if (baseWrapping == 0) {
                    wrapper.x = baseWrapping;
                    wrapper.y = baseWrapping;
                } else {
                    wrapper.x = wrapping;
                    wrapper.y = wrapping;
                }
                if (addWrapper) {
                    addChild(wrapper);
                }
            }
        }
        return sprite;
    }



    private function initialiseChildren(parent:Sprite, parentSpriteInfo:SpriteInfo, depth:int, count:int = 0):Sprite {
        var baseParent:Sprite = null;
        if (count != 0) {
            this.count = count;
        }
        do {
            var spriteParentChildren:Array = parentSpriteInfo.getChildren();

            for (var i:int = 0; i < spriteParentChildren.length; i++) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    baseParent = parent;
                }

                if (SpriteInfo(spriteParentChildren[i]).getChildrenPresent()) { //if children
                    count++;
                    var newParentSprite:Sprite = constructSprite(spriteParentChildren[i]);
                    parent.addChild(newParentSprite);
                    initialiseChildren(newParentSprite, spriteParentChildren[i], depth, count);

                } else {
                    var child:Sprite = constructSprite(spriteParentChildren[i]);
                    parent.addChild(child);
                }
            }
        } while (this.count <= depth);

        return baseParent;

    }


    private function getArrayDepth(list:Array):int {
        var depth:int = 0; //0 indexed

        for (var i:int = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var item:SpriteInfo = list[i];
            if (item.getChildrenPresent()) {
                depth++;
                depth = getArrayChildrenDepth(item.getChildren(), depth);
            }
        }
        return depth;

    }

    private function getArrayChildrenDepth(childrenList:Array, depth:int):int {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < childrenList.length; i++) {
            var item:SpriteInfo = childrenList[i];
            if (item.getChildrenPresent()) {
                depth++;
                depth = getArrayChildrenDepth(item.getChildren(), depth);
            }
        }
        return depth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
private function initialise(spritesList:Array, wraper:Sprite = null):Sprite{
    if (!wraper) wraper = new Sprite();
    var rL:uint = spritesList.length; //root length
    var cS:Sprite; // current sprite
    var chs:Array; // children of current sprite
    var allS:Vector.<Sprite> = Vector.<Sprite>([]); //all sprites.
    for (var i:int = 0; i < spritesList.length; i++){
        if (i < rL){
            cS = constructSprite(spritesList[i]);
            wraper.addChild(cS);
        }else cS = allS[i - rL];
        chs = spritesList[i].getChildren();
        if (!chs) continue;
        for (var j:int = 0; j < chs.length; j++){
            allS.push(cS.addChild(constructSprite(chs[j])));
            spritesList.push(chs[j]);
        }
    }return wraper;
}
```

I didn't test it because i don't have data for this but I hope you get the idea.

edit. Now that should work - working with data you gave me.

edit 2:

Maybe I've should follow the title of the question - here is recursive version with depth limit:

```
private var d:uint;
private var l:uint = 100;
private function contstruct(si:SpriteInfo):Sprite{
    d++;
    var ch:Array = si.getChildren();
    var s:Sprite = constructSprite(si);
    var c:uint;
    (ch) ? c = ch.length * uint(d < l): c =0;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < c; i++){
        s.addChild(contstruct(ch[i]));
    }d--; return s;
}

private function initialise(spritesList:Array, wraper:Sprite = null):Sprite {
    if (!wraper) wraper = new Sprite();
    var r:SpriteInfo = new SpriteInfo("root", "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", "", false, spritesList);
    wraper.addChild(contstruct(r));
    return wraper;
}
```

If you want to perform some operations on children before parent is create you still need to modify this but I hope that it's clear to you how.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I think that only works for a depth of one for the object.
It also has to be an array not vector.
There also doesn't appear to be any recursion to cover a spriteinfo children item which has further children.
There is no flat vector with all sprites in it either.

Comment: Did you test it? Each SpriteInfo child should be added to original array so as the loops goes on, the `spritesList.length` should be increased until there are no more children. If first generation of sprites is produced (initial `spritesList.lenght`) the loops still continues and each new `Sprite` is added to its parent. This should work for any depth level but i didn't even run this. If something is wrong you can provide me some data to test. If it's a vector or array it does not matter, you can change that quickly.

Comment: I tested this and couldn't get it to compile. I added the closing parentheses and fixed most typos (I think) but I get the following error:

[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

on line
                    for (var j:int = 0; j < chs.length; j++) {


now also, is there a need to populate any of the starting arrays with data for the declarations at the top, apart from spritesList and wrapper?

Comment: also for cS = allS[i - rL]; Isn't this going to get an out of bounds error with the array?
and  chs = spritesList[i].getChildren();  
it isn't guaranteed that every sprite will have a child.

Comment: Here is the InfoSprite class and another class that makes panels if it helps: http://justpaste.it/n5gs

Comment: I fixted those issues. I know that this is not recursive method but since one of my teachers told that some problems can't be resolved without recursion  i always try to avoid it ;) Why you think `allS[i-eL]` will throw out of bounds?

Comment: It appears to work mostly. However in another class I'm getting
 [Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #2150: An object cannot be added as a child to one of it's children (or children's children, etc.).

Comment: Fixed the problem, however is there any way to organise the function so it creates all children before the parent? I've found now there's another class which relies on the children of the parent to be created first so it can do functions on the children.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know nothing about this class so I can't  really tell but in general the `allS` contain all children sprites in order of depth so you can access the deepest child by `allS[allS.length-1]`. If you really can't call `constructSprite` on the parent first then you can't use this method as it is. I would as what you want to achive? Do you really need to use this library? You have trouble with it and it seems it's now writen very well also.

Comment: Alternatively, the easy and dirty approch will be to use `allS` array to reconstruct all children afterwards based on created 'spritesLists` - start from end of array for each sprite if it has childrens store them in temp array than reconstruct with `SpriteInfo` with index corresponding to int in `spritesList` then add children to them from temp array.

Comment: And if you are using this only to create UI then I dont think you will ever need depth checking...